# Symfony4 web.config for IIS on azure

Tags: php, symfony, azure, iis

I've deployed a symfony4 project on Azure, it uses IIS so .htaccess doesn't work. I've set the root folder on Azure app settings to "site\wwwroot\testproject\public" that folder contains index.php. I've tryed differents web.config without results.

If I open the app url it says: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

but if I open the url appending /index.php it shows the content. I need a rewrite rule like symfony/apache-pack gives for apache but for IIS.

Thanks a lit

Comment: Why are u downvoting my question? I can't provide examples since I actually need a full rewrite rule for web.config for symfony...

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive article on learn.microsoft.com on converting .htaccess to web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

I won't paste the contents here since it is very extensive and I don't use Windows and you may have custom .htaccess rules.

I suggest you to identify all .htaccess config files on your install and convert them.